# Why is ezANOVA not giving me Mauchly´s test of sphericity, even though I belive I have more than 2 levels of within-Ss variables?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, sphericity

I am trying to do learn how to do a repeated measure in R using `ezANOVA` and I have used the following command:

```
> ezANOVA(data=NL2, dv=.(ln.conc.), wid=.(sample), within=.(time),
> between=.(pH), type=1, detailed=TRUE)
```

This is my output and my question is why Mauchuly's test is not appering? I believe I have 9 levels in my within-Ss (`time=A-I`, see dataset below). The p values I get is the same as in SPSS so the test must be sort of correct...:

```
$ANOVA
Effect   DFn DFd    SSn         SSd         F        p           p<.05    ges
pH        2   6    0.09673652 0.9441442 0.3073784 7.462977e-01           0.04724473
time      8  48    1.08726236 1.0066814 6.4802768 1.065187e-05     *     0.35787718
pH:time  16  48    0.26690606 1.0066814 0.7954038 6.831493e-01           0.12035093
```

Dataset used (I have converted `time` and `pH` into letters so that R understand that it is a factor and not numericals). `ln(conc)` is measured at 3 `pH`s (`A-C`), 3 different sample sites per `pH` (`A-C`), at 9 different times (`A-I`):

```
time pH sample  ln(conc)
A   A   A   -0.862749964946125
B   A   A   -0.725670372265505
C   A   A   -0.636766847123838
D   A   A   -0.544727175441672
E   A   A   -0.681218609694672
F   A   A   -0.650087691099498
G   A   A   -0.811930716549912
H   A   A   -0.744440474947496
I   A   A   -0.881889305156823
A   A   B   -0.603306476560156
B   A   B   -0.592397277459802
C   A   B   -0.555125882662571
D   A   B   -0.534435489405125
E   A   B   -0.834710744881732
F   A   B   -0.869884359059999
G   A   B   -0.923818998294947
H   A   B   -1.14256417619729
I   A   B   -1.08767234862978
A   A   C   -0.818710403535291
B   A   C   -0.7339691750802
C   A   C   -0.755022584278033
D   A   C   -0.76142602131324
E   A   C   -0.738144546490681
F   A   C   -0.825536368605691
G   A   C   -0.936493439191674
H   A   C   -1.04412410338404
I   A   C   -1.1679623668029
A   B   D   -0.681218609694672
B   B   D   -0.449416995637347
C   B   D   -0.903868211875598
D   B   D   -0.659712404473708
E   B   D   -0.959720289801491
F   B   D   -0.657780036722654
G   B   D   -0.681218609694672
H   B   D   -0.460449416440924
I   B   D   -0.99695863494161
A   B   E   -0.358104536748327
B   B   E   -0.187535123846842
C   B   E   -0.379797361359587
D   B   E   -0.454130280089445
E   B   E   -0.574475650842447
F   B   E   -0.707246104939447
G   B   E   -0.802962046567152
H   B   E   -0.45886588483528
I   B   E   -1.14570389620196
A   B   F   -0.951917909517306
B   B   F   -0.889162064485903
C   B   F   -0.685179010910768
D   B   F   -0.685179010910768
E   B   F   -0.860383099935859
F   B   F   -0.913793851675568
G   B   F   -0.95711272639441
H   B   F   -0.944175935363691
I   B   F   -0.881889305156823
A   C   G   -0.532730459154041
B   C   G   -0.579818495252942
C   C   G   -0.603306476560156
D   C   G   -0.562118918153541
E   C   G   -0.765717873394781
F   C   G   -0.755022584278033
G   C   G   -1.03282454813011
H   C   G   -0.877070018720874
I   C   G   -1.02443289049386
A   C   H   -0.53102833108351
B   C   H   -0.563874844855806
C   C   H   -0.3147107448397
D   C   H   -0.631111789640493
E   C   H   -0.558616287602339
F   C   H   -0.703197516413447
G   C   H   -0.655851395816248
H   C   H   -0.894040122939335
I   C   H   -0.860383099935859
A   C   I   -1.02722229258144
B   C   I   -0.881889305156823
C   C   I   -0.959720289801491
D   C   I   -0.972861083362549
E   C   I   -0.881889305156823
F   C   I   -0.954511944694353
G   C   I   -0.936493439191674
H   C   I   -1.00785792539965
I   C   I   -0.911303190363116
```

Answer (score 2):

You have explicitly asked for type-1 computations, which skip the use of car::Anova and therefore miss out on its computation of assumption tests. If your data are balanced with regards to the between-Ss variable, then you can omit the `type=1` argument and receive the same results plus assumption tests. If your data aren't balanced with regards to the between-Ss variable I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Hmm, my data is balanced, but when I do > ezANOVA(data=NL, dv=.(ln.conc.), wid=.(sample), within=.(time), between=.(pH), detailed=TRUE)
I get Error in linearHypothesis.mlm(mod, hyp.matrix.1, SSPE = SSPE, V = V, idata = idata,  : 
  The error SSP matrix is apparently of deficient rank = 6 < 8
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  The car::Anova() function used to compute results and assumption tests seems to have failed. Most commonly this is because you have too few subjects relative to the number of cells in the within-Ss design.

Comment: Is my dataset entered in a wrong way?

Comment: Ah, the problem is precisely as reported by the error message: you have 6 levels of your within-Ss variable and only 6 levels of the wid variable split across 3 groups. If you leave out the effect of pH, then you can get your sphericity test, but this of course ignores pH. I frankly don't know enough about car::Anova's underlying mechanics to know why it is unable to compute the sphericity test in such cases when SPSS is able to compute it, but the developer of car is rather expert, so I wouldn't put it past SPSS to be doing something wrong.

Comment: I found out how to see the levels: > levels(time)
NULL
> levels(pH)
Error in levels(pH) : object 'pH' not found
> levels(sample)
NULL

Comment: It seems as if I do not have any levels, so I am trying to figure out that now. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Ah, I meant "levels" more abstractly, not in terms of the results from calling the `levels()` function in R. In your data you have entries in the time column that range from A-I, which is 6 letters, and that's what I meant by "6 levels of your within-Ss variable".

Comment: I figured (though A-I is 9 letters) and I hoped that R would use that also, but that does not seem to be the case. Back to "The R Book" and google for me. Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for my failure to count :p In all my responses above replace the number "6" with the number "9". So you have 9 levels of your within-Ss variable and 9 levels of wid split across 3 groups. Same argument applies: too few levels of wid to compute the full 9x3 test of sphericity.

Comment: Ok, guess I have to rethink the whole thing then. :)

Comment: If you're truly concerned about sphericity, you can move to an analysis tool that doesn't assume sphericity, like mixed effects modelling.

Comment: I think I got it now. I understand now that I can not do the sphericity test because there is no factors that can covariate with pH. I think it will be ok if tests for homogenity and variance is ok. :)